# jQuery: How to submit an array in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have the following form. Each time the users clicks `add_accommodation` I want to add to an array that I will return to the end point (`http://server/end/point`).

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/a/b/c" method="post">
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" id="Accommodation" name="accommodation"><div>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="accommodation_component">
    <div>
        <label for="AccommodationType">Type:</label>
         <input type="number" step="1" id="accommodationType" name="accommodation_type"  value="0">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="add_accommodation">Add Accommodation</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#add_accommodation').click(function() { 
            make_accommodation(this);
         });
     });

     function make_accommodation(input) {
         var value = {
             type : $("#AccommodationType").val(),
         };     
         var accommodation = $('#Accommodation').attr('id', 'accommodation');
         accommodation.push(value);
         console.log(accommodation);
     }
</script>
```

At my end point I want the result to be and array (`accommodation = [{1},{2},{3},{4}]`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the form an id, and just append a new hidden(?) input that has a name that has `[]` at the end of it, it will send the values as an array to the server.

HTML

```
<form id="myform" ...>
```

Javascript

```
function make_accommodation(){
   var newInput = $("<input>",{
      type:"hidden",
      name:"accommodation[]",
      value: {
         type: $("#AccommodationType").val()
      }
   });
   $("#myform").append(newInput);
}
```

Also you list the output as `[1,2,3,4]` but your code shows you setting the value as an object with a property `type` and setting it to the value of the accommodation input, i am going to assume that was a mistake. If I am mistaken just modify the value property in the code above.

Also in your code you change the id of the input, not sure why you were doing that as it serves no purpose and would have made your code error out so i removed it.

***EDIT***

Since you are wanting to send an array of objects, you will have to JSON.stringify the array on the client end and decode it on the server end. In this one you do not need multiple inputs, but a single one to contain the stringified data.

```
var accommodationData = [];
function make_accommodation(){
   accommodationData.push({
         type: $("#AccommodationType").val()
   });
   $("#accommodation").val( JSON.stringify(accommodationData) );
}
```

Then on the server you have to decode, not sure what server language you are using so i am showing example in PHP

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST['accommodation'] );
```

If you are using jQuery's ajax method you could simplify this by sending the array data

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url:"yourURLhere",
   type:"post"
   data:{
      accomodation:accommodationData
   },
   success:function(response){
      //whatever here
   }
});
```

Comment: The output actually is an object not numbers. I'll edit the question to reflect this. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @andre, then i will have to modify the answer as the values of inputs cannot be objects. give me a minute to reedit my answer

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` works for me. I'm using node so it's a javascript backend. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Add antorher hidden field in form

```
<input type="hidden" name="accommodation[]"> // click1
<input type="hidden" name="accommodation[]"> // click2
...
<input type="hidden" name="accommodation[]"> // clickn
```

Then when you submit form on server you will have array of accommodation.

JS part :

```
function make_accommodation() {
       $(document.createElement('input'))
             .attr('type', 'hidden')
             .attr('name', 'accommodation[]')
             .val($("#AccommodationType").val())
             .appendTo('form');
}
```

on server(PHP) :

```
print_r($_POST['accommodation']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can create a function which creates another hidden field, after clicking on the button

```
<div id='acommodation-wrapper'></div>
<button type="button" id="add_accommodation" onclick="addAnother()">Add Accommodation</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addAnother(){
        var accWrapper = $('#accommodation-wrapper');
        var count = accWrapper.children().length;     
        var div = "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"accommodation-"+count+"\" name=\"accommodation["+count+"]\"></div>";
        accWrapper.append(div);
    }
</script>
```